# How to make local glyphs and sprite to be used on my style file for my hosted map?

Tags: maps, sprite, web-hosting, endpoint, glyph

I am making a vector tile map and using Maplibre engine to show it on my website.
I used to use Maptiler but now am going to host my own personalized map on my desired Hosting Service Provider.

I need to use **sprite** and **glyphs** endpoints, which now look something like this on my style file:

```
{
"version": 8,
.
.
.
    "glyphs": "https://api.maptiler.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key=...",
    "sprite": "https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/sprite"
}
```

But I don't want to use Maptilre endpoints and want to make my own personalized files and upload them on my host and make my own endpoints.
where the result would be like:

```
{
    "version": 8,
    .
    .
    .
        "glyphs": "https://api.example.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
        "sprite": "https://api.example.com/maps/streets/sprite"
    }
```

any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use an OpenSource tool:
[TileServer-GL](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl)

So far I managed to host a server map locally, but I have some inconsistencies between online Glyphs and Local... (Maputnik online editor vs Tileserve-gl)

Here is my raised issue:
[Tileserver-gl-issues](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl/issues/712)

Comment: I am using TileServer-GL too. I asked the question a while ago and meanwhile I have worked it through. And happened to manage bring up font glyphs and sprites on my map seamlessly. You are going to have to use Tileserver-Gl as only a tile server and use a vector map renderer engine like Maplibre (which is a open-source version of Mapbox) to get it rendered on your application.

Here you can find all documents you need for rendering a map:
[maplibre](https://maplibre.org/)

Comment: If you mean how to show your map on your Maputnik editor, just
-open up [Tileserver-GL{(http://localhost:8080/)
-copy the link associated with **TileJSON** on the page
-open up Maputnik editor
-select Data Sources

Comment: If you mean how to show your map on your Maputnik editor, just
-open up [Tileserver-GL{(http://localhost:8080/)
-copy the link associated with **TileJSON** on the page
-open up Maputnik editor
-select Data Sources
-in Source Type dropdown, Select vector(Tilejson URL)
-paste what you copied earlier in TileJSON URL input
-pan to your boundary box and select inspect from view dropdown on top of the page,
And you should see your raw map ready to get styled!
you can find a few Maputnik tutorials on Youtube as well.